# HTTP Post Headers Format, Any trailing content?

Tags: java, http, post

When you receive a post request from a client, do you get any headers *after the params*?

Take this request for example:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies
```

If there are any other headers sent for any reason, would any ever appear *after* the parameters of the post content?

I am trying to figure out how to iterate post data with Java

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: @JordanSasquatchMan, is your question correctly answered? If yes, maybe you can "accept" my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Chunked Trailer Part`, the answer is Yes. In your case, the HTTP request is not chunked, so I guess the answer would be No.

According to [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1.2):

> A trailer allows the sender to include additional fields at the end
> of a chunked message in order to supply metadata that might be
> dynamically generated while the message body is sent, such as a
> message integrity check, digital signature, or post-processing
> status.  The trailer fields are identical to header fields, except
> they are sent in a chunked trailer instead of the message's header
> section.

The structure is:

```
trailer-part   = *( header-field CRLF )
```